# Stored Procedure Cross Table ID Input

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert other table's IDs (`Company` and `Bank`) into the `uBankID` and `uCompanyID` of the `EndUser` table and the `BankID` of the `Company` table on `INSERT`.

Whatever way I do this, the required fields aren't being populated, what am I doing wrong? I had a look at an inline select statement at the ID to try and grab it but couldn't fathom it and it wouldn't compile.

The variables are all present and correct in the backend and are being parsed through, all but these IDs, as nothing is going wrong with the C# I'm thinking there's something amiss with my SQL, especially as I'm fairly new to stored procedures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code (slimmed down):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcedureInsert]
    @Title nvarchar(10),
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @Organisation nvarchar(50),
    @Address nvarchar(50),
    @uBankID int,
    @uCompanyID int,
    @BankID int,
    @SortCode int,
    @AccountNumber nvarchar(50),
    @AccNameHolder nvarchar(50),
    @cId int output,
    @bId int output,
    @euId int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Bank](SortCode, AccountNumber, AccNameHolder)
    VALUES(@SortCode, @AccountNumber, @AccNameHolder)

    SET @bId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO [Company](Organisation, Address, BankID) 
    VALUES(@Organisation, @Address, @bId)

    SET @cId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO [EndUser](Title, FirstName, LastName, uBankID, uCompanyID)
    VALUES(@Title, @FirstName, @LastName, @uBankID, @cId)

    SET @euId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: it is not clear to me, are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, none. The only thing amiss is the null value in the uBankID, BankID, and uCompanyID columns.

Comment: have you configured your columns to be identity columns?

Comment: have you tried with @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Comment: No, they're integers that I wish to populate with other table's Identities.

Comment: does this happen if you run the script manually, and not from a stored procedure? Have you done this simple test?

Comment: @@IDENTITY doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you pass "@BankID" and "@uCompanyID" as parameters if you don't use them in your procedure?

Comment: Apologies, was testing directly in SQL where it worked, unsure what this issue is. I needed to declare ID variables before I used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables. And Tab Alleman is right, get rid of the unused parameters.

```
DECLARE @cId int;
DECLARE @bId int;
DECLARE @euId int;

INSERT INTO [BAD](SortCode,AccountNumber,AccNameHolder)
VALUES('1234','a234','Test Name')
SET @bId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO [Company](Organisation,Address1, Address2,City,County,PostCode,Telephone,BankID) 
VALUES('AnOrganisation','addressesss','Address2','City','County','PostCode','0123one', @bId)
SET @cId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO [EndUser](Title,FirstName,LastName,Email,uBankID,uCompanyID)
VALUES('Sitle','Fiame','astName','vv@Email',@bId,@cId)
SET @euId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

**EDIT**

Remove those parameters if they're not being used, but they weren't in the sample code, else leave them, obviously.

Also, I used single quotes to dump in the data into the table rather than variables, if it's not working then there's something wrong with the bank end code.

Comment: Never suggest using @@identity for this purpose. It is dangerous to use (ther are circumstances where it gives the wrong value) and should NEVER UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES be used to get the Identity value you just inserted. Use scope_identity() or the OUTPUT clause instead.

Comment: You're quite right - have amended the code should other's come to use it. He was initially using SCOPE_IDENTITY();